# Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $B = A^{4} + 100A^{2} + A + I$ if we know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem when the matrix A is given as follow:
$$\begin{pmatrix}11&-8&4\\-8&-1&-2\\4&-2&-4\end{pmatrix}$$
And we need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $B = A^{4} + 100A^{2} + A + I$

I can easily calculate the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of A, but really can't figure out the relation between its and that of B.

Any suggestion for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $Av = \lambda v$, then $A^i v = \lambda^i v$ for all integer $i \ge 0$, so for any polynomial $f = \sum_i a_i x^i$, 
$$f(A)v = (\sum_i a_i A^i) v = \sum_i (a_i A^i v) = \sum_i (a_i \lambda^i v) = (\sum_i a_i \lambda^i) v = f(\lambda) v$$

Comment: Can you explain more specific why $A^{i}v = \lambda^{i}v$?

Comment: If, $Av = \lambda v$ ($v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$), then: If $i = 0$ or $1$, it's trivial. If $A^i v = \lambda^i v$, then $A^{i+1} v = A A^i v = A \lambda^i v = \lambda^i A v = \lambda^i \lambda v = \lambda^{i+1} v$. Then use mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

Any eigenvector for $A$ will be an eigenvector of the matrix you described, although it will have a different eigenvalue. If $A$ has a full set of eigenvectors then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Any polynomial $p(A)$ has the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues $f(\lambda_i)$. Just insert an eigenvector $v_i$ into $p(A)v_i$ to see this.